# Installing and running JBoss EAP 7 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, jboss, jboss-eap-7

Is it possible to install JBoss EAP 7.0 on aws ec2 using the .jar installer without going through the trouble of getting a paid subscription for Red Hat Cloud Access?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding subscription is required, as per Product documentation "Membership in the Red Hat Cloud Access program provides access to supported private Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) created by Red Hat". And a quick way to launch a JBoss EAP instance on Amazon EC2 using the EC2 console.